# How to find my Google Map version in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, version

I've been asked to update the Google Maps of an existing Android app. I don't know how to determine what the version the app is currently using. How can I find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo()` to find the version of packages being used. For example:

```
try {
    Log.i("Tag", "Using Map Version: " + context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms",0).versionName);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Correcting to include the package name for Google Maps --> com.google.android.apps.maps.

Comment: I'm getting "Using Map Version: 8.2.0" (when using com.google.android.apps.maps). Where can I find the latest version? So, it's the Google Play Services SDK that provides the Maps functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this by going to Settings -> Applications -> Application Manager -> Maps Application (The version and other info shows herein)

If your question is how to update, it is updated within the play store.

Comment: pretty sure he wants to know what version of google play services he has

Comment: Yeah... not the version of the Google Maps app, but the version of Google Maps that my app uses when I display a map inside the app.